# Java cfObject with method names that are CF reserved words

Tags: java, coldfusion, braintree

I've been working on a Braintree integration in ColdFusion. Braintree does not directly support CF, but they provide a Java library and everything I've done so far has worked really well... until now.  It appears that some of the objects (particularly the search functionality) have methods that are not accessible from CF and I suspect it's because they are CF reserved words, such as "is" and "contains".  Is there any way to get around this?

```
<cfscript>
gate = createObject( "java", "com.braintreegateway.BraintreeGateway" ).init(env,merchant.getMerchantAccountId(), merchant.getMerchantAccountPublicSecret(),merchant.getMerchantAccountPrivateSecret());
req = createObject( "java","com.braintreegateway.CustomerSearchRequest").id().is("#user.getUserId()#");
customer = gate.customer().search(req);
</cfscript>
```

The error thrown:  Invalid CFML construct ... ColdFusion was looking at the following text: is

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This represents a bug in the CF compiler.  There is no rule in CF that one cannot define a method called either `is()` or `this()`, and indeed in basic situations there's no problem with calling them either.  This code demonstrates:

```
<!--- Junk.cfc --->
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="is">
        <cfreturn true>
    </cffunction>
    <cffunction name="contains">
        <cfreturn true>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>

<!--- test.cfm --->
<cfset o = new Junk()>

<cfoutput>
    #o.is()#<br />
    #o.contains()#<br />
</cfoutput>
```

This - predictably - outputs:

```
true
true
```

However we have problems if we introduce a init() method to Junk.cfc, thus:

```
<cffunction name="init">
    <cfreturn this>
</cffunction>
```

And then adjust test.cfm accordingly:

```
#o.init().is()#<br />
#o.init().contains()#<br />
```

This causes a compiler error:

> Invalid CFML construct found on line 4 at column 19.
>
> ColdFusion was looking at the following text:
>
> is
>
> [...]
>
> coldfusion.compiler.ParseException: Invalid CFML construct found on line 4 at column 19.
>
> ```
> at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.generateParseException(cfml40.java:12135)
> ```
>
> [etc]

There is no valid reason why `o.init().is()` should not be OK if `o.is()` is fine.

I recommend you [file a bug](https://bugbase.adobe.com/).  I'll vote for it.

**As a workaround** you should be fine if you use intermediary values, rather than method chaining.

Comment: Oh, and intermediary values made no difference.

Comment: Eh?  Show us the modified code and the exact error msg pls.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use the [Java Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html) to invoke the is() method on your object.

I'd also raise a call with Adobe to see if they'll fix it or provide their own workaround. I can understand disallowing defining your own method or variable called 'is', but attempting to invoke it here should be safe.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to this problem.  At least a fix to get you up and running.

Try this code.

```
<cfscript>
    //Get our credentials here, this is a custom private function I have, so your mileage may vary
    credentials = getCredentials();

    //Supply the credentials for the gateway    
    gateway = createObject("java", "com.braintreegateway.BraintreeGateway" ).init(credentials.type, credentials.merchantId, credentials.publicKey, credentials.privateKey);

    //Setup the customer search object  
    customerSearch = createObject("java", "com.braintreegateway.CustomerSearchRequest").id();

    //can't chain the methods here for the contains, since it's a reserved word in cf.  lame.
    customerSearchRequest = customerSearch.contains(arguments.customerId);

    //Build the result here
    result = gateway.customer().search(customerSearchRequest);
</cfscript>
```